# jquery ajax cross domain script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to load content on my website. In my ajax page, it contains some of script tag:

```
<script src="/js/tinymce.js"></script>
```

The ajax page does load the script when the page loads. However, after I put the script source to public domain, it doesn't load the script.

```
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Why is it does not load script from public cdn / cross domain? How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your page directly from your local computer file system (`file://`) ?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Nope. I am running it from localhost

Comment: Is there any error showing up in the console and the Network tab in the console?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Basically the error that cannot load tinymce: `tinymce is not defined` which shows the script is not loaded.

Comment: Take a look at the Network tab and see if the file says `200 OK`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I tested on several browser and found that older browser don't work. Do you have any idea to make it work on older version of browser such as IE 8, 9, 10, Firefox 19?

Comment: It should work in all browsers that has JavaScript enabled (at least it should have loaded it.)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I found out why it doesn't work. Because on old browser, when the script is cross-domain, it will run the inline script first before the cross-domain script is loaded. Therefore it causes error. How can I have my inline script run last after everything is loaded in ajax? Thanks.

Comment: execute your code when the window is loaded (`window.onload`)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>That is because anything after `//` has to be a valid domain. `public_CDN` is definitely not a valid domain name, as it does not contain a `gTLD`. (`.com`, `.net` etc..).</strike>

### Update

It seems that you are not running it in a web server. You are allowed to use protocol less urls  `//something.com` only if you are running it in a server.

Try using the url with `http://`

```
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what I put here is just the example, not the real path.

Comment: I am running it from web server. I have try with adding http:// in front, but it is still the same.